# How are probability density functions, that are computed from real-world datasets, stored and represented by computational software?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, density-function, density-estimation

In probability and statistics, density estimation is the construction of an estimate, based on observed data, of an unobservable underlying probability density function. The unobservable density function is thought of as the density according to which a large population is distributed; the data are usually thought of as a random sample from that population.

Here, I am explicitly referring to probability density functions that are not parametric.

Then my question is: How are these probability density functions, which are in practice computed from real-world datasets, stored and represented by computational software?

Comment: In many, many ways.  Sometimes they aren't even computed.  On this site alone you can find examples where they are represented symbolically; embodied as various algorithms; approximated with various functions; represented as mixtures; interpolated among irregular points on a graph; represented as gridded values (in one or more dimensions); indirectly represented in terms of the cdf, mgf, cf, or cgf; and simply sketched on a piece of paper and photographed.

Comment: Which probability density functions exactly?

Comment: For example the density function of a continuous action A conditioned on some covariates W $p(A \mid W)$ or the density function representing the pixel intensity $I$ in a video given the horizontal location $X_1$ in any single frame of the video $p(I \mid X_1)$.